# take a value form searchname column and find it into column A if available then in next column B will print Master customer column

Tags: excel, vba

shhet1(Searchname)
Column

```
**Searchnames                       Master Customer**
Carestream Health                       Carestream Health
Computer Sciences Corporation     Computer Sciences Corporation
Enterasys                                Enterasys
Freescale Semiconductor            Freescale Semiconductor
Micron Technology                       Micron Technology
Nichia Corporation                      Nichia Corporation
STMicroelectronics                      STMicroelectronics

shhet2(Preselling)
column A,B
Below vlaues are in Column A
```

**Customer(Column Heading)**

```
DF Australia Pty Carestream Health
DEC LTD.INTERNATIONAL
Kazakhstan Petrochemical Industrials In Carestream Health
MASCO CORPORATION
Target Stores
FLSMIDTH A/S
KBR
FLSMIDTH A/S
haerbin electric group
```

I have two excel sheet(searchname, preselling), in searchname sheet i have two colums(Searchnames,Master Customer). so i want to take a vaule from searchname column and find that similer value into second sheet in column "A". if that value is present in column A. so in next column B will print the value present in Master Customer column

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried vlookups?

Vlookups will help you find a value from another column in another sheet that matches a particular cell. Note it will only pick up one value

http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/ss/vlookup.htm